# Evaluate function from list in lisp

Tags: list, function, functional-programming, lisp

I need to write a function in lisp with two arguments - list of argumentless functions and list of integers.
I need to evaluate functions from first list in order given by a second, i.e. (fun '(#'a #'b #'c) '(2 0 1)) should evaluate c, a, b.
I tried such function:

```
(defun z4(funs kols)
    (funcall (nth (first kols) funs))
    (z4 funs (rest kols))
)
```

but in funcall I am geting error

> NIL is not of type CONS.

What does it means? I am getting same error by calling simply

```
(funcall (first funs))
```

so I assume it is something with with getting function from the list of functions. How can I evaluate function get from list of functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With each recursive call you reduce the `kols` parameter untill it becomes `nil`. When `kols` becomes `nil` you should terminate the recursion, so you should add the test for the terminating condition (i.e., for empty list):

```
(defun foo (funcs order)
  (unless (endp order)
    (funcall (nth (first order) funcs))
    (foo funcs (rest order))))
```

I suggest a more readable solution (it's also more preferrable since ANSI Common Lisp Standard doesn't force implementations to perform tail call optimization):

```
(defun foo (funcs order)
  (loop for n in order do (funcall (nth n funcs))))
```

In the previous examples I assume that you run your functions for their side effects, not for the return values.

---

**Edit 1**

As Vatine noted, using `nth` and lists to provide a collection with random access is not good for the performance, so it might be worth to store functions in a `vector` (that is a one-dimensional `array`) rathen than in a list. So, assuming that `funcs` is a `vector` of functions, the function can be defined as follows:

```
(defun foo (funcs order)
  (loop for n in order do (funcall (aref funcs n))))
```

Moreover, we can replace `aref` with `svref` if the array of functions is a `simple vector` ([glossary entry](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#simple_vector)). The former is more general, but the latter may be faster in some implementations.

One can create a `simple vector` of functions using either

```
(vector #'func-a #'func-b ...)
```

or

```
#(func-a func-b ...)
```

A `simple vector` of functions can be created using the `make-array` function as well, but only if `:adjustable` and `:fill-pointer` keyword arguments are unspecified or `nil`.

Comment: Do note that nth is O(N) on lists, so it MAY be a speed advantage to turn the list-of-functions into an array-of-functions.

Answer (score 4):

```
'(#'a #'b #'c)
```

is not a list of functions A, B, C. It is this:

```
((FUNCTION A) (FUNCTION B) (FUNCTION C))
```

Above are not functions, but lists with the first symbol `FUNCTION` and then another symbol.

Use either

```
(list #'a #'b #'c)
```

or

```
'(a b c)
```